# which tomcat version is suitable for java 8

Tags: java, tomcat, version, upgrade

Recently, our online web service using tomcat 7.0.23.0 and JVM 1.7.0_51-b13 need to upgrade to java 8, which tomcat version is suitable for java 8 ?

Comment: Library/framework/tool recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow. Try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), and delete this Stack Overflow post if you decide to migrate there.

Comment: The best version will be the most recent stable version.  Currently Tomcat 8.5. My guess is that they will announce the EOL date for Tomcat 7 in a year or so. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996375/apache-tomcat-7-eol-prediction

Comment: Also note that running an online service without patching your Tomcat and Java is ... unwise.  Java 7 is 2.5 years past EOL, and Tomcat 7.0.23 is missing 6 (yes **SIX**) years of security updates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this link

http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

for details about which tomcat versions are supported on which java versions.

According to that link, tomcat 7.0.23.0 should work on java 8

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat 7 is good and works well for Java 8 however, not recommended for Java8 as all features of Java 8 were not supported in tomcat 7.
Please use **tomcat 9.x with Java 8** (Recommended from Tomcat Apache)

Please refer http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Answer (score 2):

Latest stable version supported on Java 8 is Tomcat 10 but the users of Tomcat 10 onwards should be aware that, as a result of the move from Java EE to Jakarta EE as part of the transfer of Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation, the primary package for all implemented APIs has changed from javax.* to jakarta.*.